# I'm beginner on laravel. And i have encountered Connection error with mysql on laravel version 5.4.16

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

This is my route code to add tables into firstapp db

```
Route::get('/', function () 
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
    });        
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And this is config\database.php file's code

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'firstapp'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

But there are two errors.Please give me solution for this.

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

And

> PDOException in Connector.php line 68:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: upload database schema

Comment: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` - is MySQL running?

Comment: i have uploaded schema code.@BilalAhmed. at the top

Comment: Look for **migrations** in the Laravel documentation. That's the correct way to create a table in Laravel. By using this, your script attempts to create a table every time you reload the main page. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations

Comment: You mean i should create tables using migrations???

Answer (score 4):

You have to modify env file. There is database configurations that has to modified first than you have to modify `database.php` file like

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Your Db Name
DB_USERNAME=Your Db username
DB_PASSWORD=Your Db Password
```

Comment: sir please specify the location of .env file.

Comment: .env file is available in root folder of your project.

Comment: if you are looking for this in IDE than some IDE is not showing hidden files.. so make sure about this.

Comment: sir i have changed both files .env and .env.example files.

Comment: are you using latest version of phpmyadmin ?

Comment: i'm using v3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You should add .env file, see .envexample, and add db configurations, hostname, password, db name.

Comment: sir i'm not uderstanding .env file.

Comment: i have changed database.php file in config folder

Comment: In laravel db configurations set in .env file,  .env file should be under root directory, after laravel intalation, there is .envexample file, you can see and create your .env file with your configurations, Please chek documentation of laravel about .env file.

Comment: In your case it looks like MySQL has not started as you are getting the message that indicates there is no server running and therefore listening for requests. Try start mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' =>'firstapp',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
],
```

Please Try it